# Run Cypher file present in S3 using apoc.cypher.runFile

Tags: amazon-s3, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to run call apoc.cypher.runFile(""), but it returns Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.cypher.runFile`: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: (my presigned url for the s3 file)
I want to know if it is possible to import cypher scripts stored in the s3 bucket, by using the presigned url and the apoc.cypher.runFile stored procedure.

Please help!!
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this documentation below, you need to add this in your config and restart the server.

> We can enable reading files from anywhere on the file system by setting the following property in apoc.conf:

```
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=false
```

Ref:    https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.cypher/apoc.cypher.runFile/

Comment: Hello @jose_bacoy, I have already done this, and it works well for importing files in the local machine, but I am not able to import cypher file present in AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: it does not allow S3 bucket or public IP. Only local files. If you want to try, use LOAD CSV since it allows external filesystem.